# Edits made by Pywikibot edits not showing up in Recent Changes

Tags: mediawiki-api, pywikibot

As the title says, I cannot see the edits made via the API with Pywikibot in Recent Changes, even with all filters removed. I can see the list of edits when I go to the User Contributions page of the user account (which is in the Bots user group).

Here is the setup of my wiki:

| Product | Version |
| --- | --- |
| MediaWiki | 1.39.4 |
| PHP | 7.4.33 (fpm-fcgi) |
| MariaDB | 10.4.20-MariaDB-1:10.4.20+maria~buster-log |
| ICU | 65.1 |

I am working with pywikibot version 8.3.2.

One big reason I want my edits to show up is in case I need to delete all the pages created in a run (which is probably 200-300 pages), and Mass Delete only works on edits that show up in Recent Changes--so Mass Delete doesn't see any of these new pages.

Is there a setting somewhere in the Pywikibot configuration to change this behavior? Or, is there some weird setting in my Mediawiki that I need to change? Thanks!